# How can I link two Apify scrapers?

Tags: apify

I have a web scraper and a cheerio scraper which both extract data from the same list of webpages, how can I make one task call the other when it is completed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use webhooks, put your run task endpoint on a Run Succeeded webhook. make sure your task is already properly configured when starting it. You can omit the payload template setting it as `{}`

[image]